# How to make my live site responsive in typo3 templovoila 6.2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, typo3-6.2.x

I have a live website in server in Typo3 templavoila version 6.2. Now I wanna make it responsive. So How do I implement the bootstrap in typo3? Please help me in this concern. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hire a developer to modify your theme, build a new theme, or find a theme that is already responsive.

Comment: okay! thanks  a lot for ur kind help!

Answer (score 0):

**Funny Question** but answer is: you can find free template as your requirement from google of `typo3 CMS` read documentation of the downloaded theme install it simply if still facing problem simple :) hire me or any developer.